# Insert weekend dates into dataframe while keeping prices in index location

Tags: pandas, dataframe, date, currency

I have a pandas DataFrame with dates, open and close prices of USD that looks something like this:

```
Date        Open     Close
2021-12-08  0.88707  0.88680
2021-12-07  0.88617  0.88600
2021-12-06  0.88475  0.88458
2021-12-03  0.88442  0.88447
2021-12-02  0.88342  0.88343
2021-12-01  0.88261  0.88259
```

I am wanting to insert the weekend dates and keep my open and close values at the same dates and fill the empty Open and Close values with NaN, something like this:

```
Date        Open     Close
2021-12-08  0.88707  0.88680
2021-12-07  0.88617  0.88600
2021-12-06  0.88475  0.88458
2021-12-05  NaN      NaN
2021-12-04  NaN      NaN
2021-12-03  0.88261  0.88259
2021-12-02  0.88342  0.88343
2021-12-01  0.88261  0.88259
```

I have tried various techniques such as creating a new DataFrame with my open and close values then reindexing by the date:

```
df_USD_new = {'Open':open_USD,
    'Close':close_USD}

df = pd.DataFrame(df_USD_new)

df

date_index = pd.date_range('2016-12-01', '2021-12-08', freq='D')

df.reindex(date_index)
```

But this gives me a tables with all dates filled as NaN such as:

```
2021-12-04  NaN NaN
2021-12-05  NaN NaN
2021-12-06  NaN NaN
2021-12-07  NaN NaN
2021-12-08  NaN NaN
```

Am I doing something wrong or missing a step? Would appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df.set_index('Date', inplace=True)
df = df.reindex(pd.date_range(df.index.min(), df.index.max())).sort_index(ascending=False).reset_index().rename(columns={'index': 'Date'})
```

`OUTPUT`

```
        Date     Open    Close
0 2021-12-08  0.88707  0.88680
1 2021-12-07  0.88617  0.88600
2 2021-12-06  0.88475  0.88458
3 2021-12-05      NaN      NaN
4 2021-12-04      NaN      NaN
5 2021-12-03  0.88442  0.88447
6 2021-12-02  0.88342  0.88343
7 2021-12-01  0.88261  0.88259
```

Or you can also use this:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df.set_index('Date', inplace=True)
df = df.asfreq('d').sort_index(ascending=False).reset_index().rename(columns={'index': 'Date'})
```